# How can I delete root (admin) users that have same UID(0) as root?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, arch-linux, root

This is my passwd file:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
m:x:0:100::/home/m:/bin/bash
masoudjjgh:x:1000:100:masoudjjgh:/home/masoudjjgh:/bin/bash
```

I try to delete user *m* that I am created:

```
[root@...]# userdel m
[root@...]# userdel: user m is currently used by process 1
```

And when I try to kill m by this command:

```
[root@...]# killall -KILL -u m
```

desktop `(kde)`, `console` and anything exited and `logged` me off automatically. All things close and I must `login` again. userdel will again close all.
Is there anyway to remove `m`?

I created it, but now I can't delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash  
m:x:0:100::/home/m:/bin/bash
[...]
# userdel: user m is currently used by process 1
# killall -KILL -u m
```

Processes and files are actually owned by user ID numbers, not user names. `m` and `root` have the same UID, so everything owned by one is also owned by the other. Based on your description, it sounds like both `userdel` and `killall` saw every root process (UID 0) as belonging to this user "m".

According to [this sample man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel), `userdel` has an option `-f` to force removal of the account even if it has active processes. And `userdel` would *probably* just delete m's passwd entry and home directory, without affecting the actual root account.

To be safer, I might be inclined to hand-edit the password file to remove the entry for m, then hand-remove m's home directory. You may have a command on your system named `vipw`, which lets you safely edit `/etc/passwd` in a text editor.

Comment: `same UID` very important point that you see it.
than i can change m'UID , restart and then remove m. yes?

Comment: Yes. I would expand Kenster's suggestion to say: manually edit the password file *to change `m`'s UID to a number not used by any other user*, and then do `userdel m`. It should not be necessary to restart.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the lines in your passwd and shadow files in your /etc directory manually first. You can then rm -fR the home directory for that user account. (m in your example)

Additional files will still have to be removed. For example:

/var/spool/mail/m

This is a very surgical approach to use when userdel refuses to work.

Comment: tnx its work.
but perhaps few thing not delete.

Comment: tnx. very good command.
i try it and see very good files that must be deleted.

Comment: `find / -user m` is really questionable here. This "m" user has UID 0, which is also root's UID. So there's no distinction between files owned by "m" and files owned by "root".

Answer (score 2):

in /etc/passwd file change the guid of the user you want to delete to something other than 0. Then attempt a userdel.

Source: http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Create-USER-with-ROOT-Privileges-in-Linux

Comment: This is essentially the same as just removing that line from the passwd file. You're effectively detaching the user from everything it owns, and leaving any remnants behind.

Answer (score 1):

It will made you some problem, because some of problem, need of `root.rootfor running. I have a better suggestion:

1. Import an account to `/etc/suders` as:

   ```
   youraccount   ALL=(ALL) ALL
   ```
2. Change root user as `/bin/false` as a non-login user.

Comment: +1 Good answer, while it did not actually answer the question asked - which was how to delete a root user, it gave a different (SAFER) way to log in.

Comment: tnx mohsen. by jeff'command (find -user *) i find very files that i must see those and perhaps delete manulay!

Answer (score 0):

userdel has a `-f, --force` flag to force deleting the account, even if the user is still logged on. The `-r, --remove` flag deletes the home directory and mail spool as well.

You can try to delete user `m` with:

```
userdel -fr m
```